# Firebase onMessageReceived not called

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

FCM service:

```
public class FCMService extends FirebaseMessagingService {


    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {


        Log.i(Constants.TAG,"onMessageReceived");

        Log.i(Constants.TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            Log.d(Constants.TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());
        }


        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            Log.d(Constants.TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        }


    }

}
```

App Gradle:

```
  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.6'
```

Manifest:

```
   <service android:name="communications.FCMService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

-I send message [from FCM console](https://console.firebase.google.com) and don´t arrives. FCM console show me OK when message is sent.

-I send message from java server and message don´t arrives. Java server show me OK when message is sent.

-To send messages I use generated token in Android device.

-Before, I had a mistake to import the FCM library badly, that error is solved. When that past error occurred every time a message was sent, an exception occurred on Android. Now nothing is received.

-I have on the Android device an Internet connection and I receive messages via GCM (not FCM) from another application that I implemented in the past.

-App is in foreground.

Some log with "fcm" filter. I get this log when I send message.

```
08-14 12:09:25.640 800-4739/? D/PowerManagerService: acquireWakeLockInternal: lock=862109980, flags=0x1, tag="wake:bidsy.app.bidsy/communications.FCMService", ws=null, uid=10354, pid=24073
08-14 12:09:25.640 800-4739/? D/PowerManagerNotifier: onWakeLockAcquired: flags=1, tag="wake:bidsy.app.bidsy/communications.FCMService", packageName=bidsy.app.bidsy, ownerUid=10354, ownerPid=24073, workSource=null
08-14 12:09:25.683 24073-24073/bidsy.app.bidsy D/ActivityThread: SVC-Creating service: CreateServiceData{token=android.os.BinderProxy@1c269013 className=communications.FCMService packageName=bidsy.app.bidsy intent=null}
08-14 12:09:25.683 24073-24073/bidsy.app.bidsy D/ActivityThread: SVC-CREATE_SERVICE handled : 0 / CreateServiceData{token=android.os.BinderProxy@1c269013 className=communications.FCMService packageName=bidsy.app.bidsy intent=null}
08-14 12:09:25.685 24073-24073/bidsy.app.bidsy D/ActivityThread: SVC-SERVICE_ARGS handled : 0 / ServiceArgsData{token=android.os.BinderProxy@1c269013 startId=1 args=Intent { act=com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT pkg=bidsy.app.bidsy cmp=bidsy.app.bidsy/communications.FCMService (has extras) }}
08-14 12:09:25.684 24073-24073/bidsy.app.bidsy D/ActivityThread: SVC-Calling onStartCommand: communications.FCMService@3e035250, flags=0, startId=1
08-14 12:09:25.691 800-1592/? D/PowerManagerService: releaseWakeLockInternal: lock=862109980 [wake:bidsy.app.bidsy/communications.FCMService], flags=0x0, total_time=52ms
08-14 12:09:25.691 800-1592/? D/PowerManagerNotifier: onWakeLockReleased: flags=1, tag="wake:bidsy.app.bidsy/communications.FCMService", packageName=bidsy.app.bidsy, ownerUid=10354, ownerPid=24073, workSource=null
08-14 12:09:25.692 24073-24073/bidsy.app.bidsy D/ActivityThread: SVC-Destroying service: communications.FCMService@3e035250
```

It seems like the message arrives at the service but does not show it.

Of course I do not use any filters in the log to check if the message gets to onMessageReceived

I find similar question here not answered, has same log:

[Can't receive the push notification message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41938542/cant-receive-the-push-notification-message)

**After looking at the whole log in detail I have seen that when I send a message the following Firebase error occurs**:

```
D / FirebaseMessaging: Unknown intent action: com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT
```

**Solution to my problem is here**:

[I faced a issue while using the older version of FCM i.e 10.2.6 Unknown intent action: com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44772951/i-faced-a-issue-while-using-the-older-version-of-fcm-i-e-10-2-6-unknown-intent-a)

Comment: Are you sure that your authorization key and device token are still valid.. device tokens will change when you reinstall.. Make sure your google-services.json is also valid

Comment: In each test I uninstalled the app and generated a new token. The Android Firebase tool tells me that the app is linked to the project correctly.

Comment: Do your messages have a "data" payload? Messages without data payload (like from console) won't arrive in FirebaseMessagingService.

Comment: I send message from FCM console. The text of the message is mandatory.

Comment: Yes it is, but if your payload does not have a "data" part, this messages won't arrive in your MessagingService, though they get displayed.

Comment: And how can I send "data" part from the console?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firebase onMessageReceived not called when app in background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37358462/firebase-onmessagereceived-not-called-when-app-in-background)

Comment: refer this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42273699/how-to-stack-firebase-cloud-messaging-notifications-when-the-application-is-not/43914028#43914028

Answer (score 21, accepted):

1. tl;dr

---

Your messages, that are send from somewhere, need to have a **data payload** and **no** notification payload, or they won't arrive *consistently* inside of "onMessageReceived" in your MessagingService.

> Notification messages contain a predefined set of user-visible keys. Data messages, by contrast, contain only your user-defined custom key-value pairs. Notification messages can contain an optional data payload.

(`"Notification messages can contain an optional data payload"`, this will only get submitted to your service, if your application is in foreground!)

- Messages created from the console will always be notification-messages!
- **You can't send plain data-messages, that will consistently arrive at your service through the firebase-console. This is only possible via the [REST-API (FCM protocols)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server#choose) or the [Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/admin/).**

One more important thing:

If you send Notification Messages with a data payload, that you wish to handle, you **must** handle not only it via the service if the app is in foreground, but also gathering the data from the **Intent that your Launch-Activity will receive**, which will be opened, if the user clicks the notification! The data payload will be inside of the intent!

---

2. Types of messages:

---

**Notification Messages** and **Data Messages**.

1. Notification messages contain a predefined set of user-visible keys. Notification messages have an optional *data payload*.

- If the app is in foreground, they will call `onMessageReceived` **(you need to handle the display of the notification on your own)**
- If the application is background, the notification will be displayed (user system tray) and if there is a data payload, it is delivered in the extras of the intent of your launcher Activity.

2. Data Messages contain only your user-defined custom key-value pairs. (explained below). And if you want that **the message consistently call the onMessageReceived, they should not contain a notification payload, but only a data payload.**

From the docs:

> Client app is responsible for processing data messages. Data messages
> have only custom key-value pairs. (! once again - only custom key-value pairs)

You can read about the message types **here**: [Fcm Message Types](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages)

---

3. Data Payload

---

The data payload is a simple json entry, additionally in your payload
and can have simple key, value pairs.

Example:

```
  "data": {
        "eventId" : "1",
        "flavors" : "alpha",
        "minFcmVersion" : "3",
        "showFallbackOnLowVersion" : "false"
  }
```

Inside of the console, you can add the data payload, if you enter something below the "extended options" field:

[image]

**Messages created  from the console will always be notification-messages!**

At first, send a firebase cloud message via the console, directly to your
device (use the fcm token) and add a simple data-payload with example values.
Now check if your services onMessageReceived is called. (You app must be in foreground!)

**Backend**

With the REST API you can send Data-Messages, that only contain custom key-value pairs and will always arrive to your service!

Your backend should compose the message itself and add a data payload.
This is somewhat described here: [HTTP protocol data payload](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#data)

You can also test a *backend* wise sent message via one of the several
http request builder you find online. I like: [hurl.it](https://www.hurl.it/) and

`Post` to:

> https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send

4. Gradle

---

`com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.0.0` **<- use this**, or higher

*That said, there was a bug in versions lower then* `'11.0.4'`.

5. Links and good read

---

Further good to read documentation here: [Receive Messages Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive)
And a good explanation on message types as an SOF Answer: [SOF - Answer - Message Types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37711082/how-to-handle-notification-when-app-in-background-in-firebase/37845174#37845174)

Comment: I have tried to send a message from console and it keeps coming but it does not call the service method. I updated my initial post at bottom to the possible cause of the problem.

Comment: Solved using 11.0.1' instead of 10.2.6. Problem also is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44772951/i-faced-a-issue-while-using-the-older-version-of-fcm-i-e-10-2-6-unknown-intent-a

Comment: Good to know that it now works with 11.0.4. Happy coding :)

Comment: OnMessageRecieved never called when App is in background

Comment: @ZaidMirza I made it more clear and edited the answer. For you in short: All messages created through the console, are always Notification - Messages and will only call your onMessageReceived Service method, if your app is in foreground. You need a backend that calls the API!

Comment: I added how to handle notification messages, with optional datapayload.

Answer (score 0):

try below cases

1. Check your google play service installed in your device are up to date. If its not, try to [update](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.gms&hl=en)
2. Make sure your java server code are in right order , for example

   HttpResponse response = Unirest.post("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send")
     .header("authorization", "key=your_firebase_key")
     .header("content-type", "application/json")
     .header("cache-control", "no-cache")
     .header("postman-token", "836e187a-c342-ce8a-3a2d-f541a4d8e416")
     .body("{\r\n\"to\" :\"your_device_token\",\r\n\"data\" : {\r\n\"message\": \"Checking pushnotification\"\r\n}\r\n\t\r\n}")
     .asString();

   3. Check your Log in the FCMService class

Comment: So FCM is working. Did you add firebase using firebase tool in android studio or manually ?

Comment: Both ways. First I used the tool, as it did not work I have tried to do it all manual.