# Open deep link through firebase notification

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, deep-linking, android-navigation-graph

I want to open a specific fragment in my navigation graph through deep linking.

I added a deep link URL like this
[image]

I tried putting the same URL in the payload in the FCM console, but it did not open my fragment, the same thing opens when I put the URL in a text message.

[image]

I have added the nav graph in manifest too, can someone please address what's wrong and how can I fix it.

Answer (score 0):

If your navigation graph is in an Activity other than the launcher activity. Call `setComponentName(<your_class_name::class.java>)` while building the Deep link.

```
NavDeepLinkBuilder(context)
    .setGraph(R.navigation.menu_job_navgraph)
    .setComponentName(MainActivity::class.java)
    .setDestination(R.id.jobDetailFrag)
    .setArguments(JobDetailFragsArg("1").toBundle())
    .createPendingIntent()
```

Comment: Hi, your method is working but it just opens the destination page when the app is in foreground, but when it's in background it simple opens the app, can you please tell what's the issue?

Comment: If your app is in the background, onMessageReceived might not be called. refer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45671869/firebase-onmessagereceived-not-called/45673611#45673611

Comment: I tried using postman too I added this code to my activity <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:host="siddhesh.com"
                    android:scheme="http" />

            </intent-filter>